# Can't set cell title's text

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I'm writing simple notes app, but when I try to assign title to note.title I got error.

```
-(Notez*)createNoteWithTitle:(NSString*)titleNote andText:(NSString*)textNote
{
    Notez *newNote  = [Notez new];
    if (!_notesArray) {
        _notesArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    }
    newNote.dateCreated = [NSDate new];
    newNote.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"23"];
    newNote.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"233"];
    [_notesArray addObject:newNote];
    return newNote;
    }
```

Notez.h :
     #import

```
 @interface Notez : NSObject
 @property NSString *text;
 @property NSString *title;
 @property NSDate* dateCreated;
 -(Notez*)createNoteWithTitle:(NSString*)title andText:(NSString*)text;
-(void)save;
+(instancetype)sharedManager;
-(NSArray*)sortedNotes;
-(void)removeNoteAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
@end
```

note.dateCreated is OK, but note.title and note.text isn't.

They are both NSString...

```
- (IBAction)addNote:(id)sender {
    [[Notez sharedManager] createNoteWithTitle:@"Note Title" andText:@"Note Text"];
}
```

Comment: 1) You need to provide a lot more details about your `Note` class. 2) Don't misuse `stringWithFormat`. Just do `newNote.title = @"23";`.

Comment: this is implementation when tapping + BarButtonItem

Comment: can you share the `Notez.h` file with us?

Comment: And don't add more details in the comments. Update your question with the additional code and information.

Comment: You should use [NSString stringWithString:@"23"] instead of stringWithFormat in this example.

Comment: @Greg No, just use `= @"23";`.

Comment: and what exactly is the error that you have?

Comment: @wootage 2014-11-06 18:59:46.628 SpeakToNote[3554:1131820] -[Notez setTitle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fbe9b419590
2014-11-06 18:59:46.630 SpeakToNote[3554:1131820] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Notez setTitle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fbe9b419590'

Comment: It may not be the place for this comment, but I feel that the structure of this class is really unconventional. You should consider making `createNoteWithTitle:andText:` into a class method instead of an instance method. As it stands, you could call it on any instance (not just your `sharedManager` .. which, incidentally, isn't a manager at all).

Comment: @IanMacDonald Yes, but this worked fine for another app.

Comment: And what does reason: '-[Notez setTitle:]: means ? I have no [notez setTitle] in my code ... Or it isn't string from code ?

Comment: `setTitle:` is a _setter_ method that you get for free when declaring properties. that's the whole point of a property, that it is an instance variable for which you automatically have _getters_ and _setters_

Comment: There's something you're not showing us.

Comment: The problem is in newNote.title = .... ; And I can't understand why. Is there some way to do it like [newNote.title setString : text]; or something like that ?   SharedManager isn't problem . It works fine. After debugging it I got problem in : newNote.title = @"";

Comment: You have most likely done something to prevent the setter for `title` from getting generated.  Not sure what it might be, since you're not showing us all the code.

Comment: Hah , YUP , THERE WAS Something

Comment: `newNote.title = xxx` is entirely equivalent to `[newNote setTitle:xxx]`.  The "setter" `setTitle:` should be generated automatically, but you've done something to prevent that.

Comment: I don't know why but I got code with @dynamic title;
 Actually , I don't know why I got this, but that was a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you declared `title` and `text` as properties, but for some reason get the exception: 
**[Notez setTitle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance**, apparently

I can only make another guess here. Usually, when declaring a property, you get a `setter` and a `getter` method for it. This way you can omit writing these by hand if you have a lot of instance variables on a class.

Using `dot notation` is then equivalent to calling the `setter` or the `getter`. So in your case

`newNote.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"23"];`

is equivalent to:

`[newNote setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"23"]];`

Now, the exception that you suggests that the `setter` method:  `setTitle:` actually does not exist on your object. I'm not sure what the reason for this might be, but you could try to explicitly *synthesize* your properties.

Therefor, in your **.m-file** add the following lines of code:

```
@synthesize title;
@synthesize text;
```

Not sure if this will actually solve your issue, but I hope the explanation of `properties`, `getters` and `setters` helps you to understand a little more what's going on.

Comment: Yes , I got dynamic instead of synthesize.

Comment: @GeorgeSabanov You don't want `@dynamic` or `@synthesize`.